# How does ndarray.__new__ know from where it is being called?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, subclassing

In the numpy documentation of subclassing ndarray [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html#the-role-of-array-finalize). It is said that

> `ndarray.__new__`, passes `__array_finalize__` the new object, of our own
> class (`self`) as well as the object from which the view has been taken
> (`obj`).

I understand `ndarray.__new__` can create the new object `self` and pass that to `__array_finalize__`, but how does it get the `obj` from where it is called? From the signature of `ndarray.__new__`, looks like `obj` does not get passed from the calling function. So does `ndarray.__new__` use some deep magic (probably at the C level) to determine where it is called (i.e. constructor call, view casting or new from template)?

Comment: It's passed in.  Look at the examples; the only cases where it is able to pass in the `obj` is when the object is being passed to the constructor.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get what you meant. When the `ndarray.__new__` function is called from a constructor call, `obj` should be passed as `None` to `__array_finalize__`.

Comment: There are three examples at the link you posted, showing the three different cases.  I'm curious as to why you care -- this is an obscure corner of numpy that will never matter to 99% of programmers.

Comment: Simply my curiosity. I think my question is more on how does `ndarray.__new__` know which `obj` to pass to `__array_finalize__` because there is no parameter allowing the passing of `obj` into `ndarray.__new__`.

Comment: In the cases where it DOES know (where we are initializing from another object), it passed the object.  In the cases where it DOESN'T know, it passes `None`.

Comment: Thank you. But what is the mechanism that allows `ndarray.__new__` to know whether it is being called from constructor call, view casting or new from template? I think your answer assumes that `ndarray.__new__` already knows that information and my question is more on how does it know it.

Comment: If it's coming from a view, then the object is passed in to `__new__`.  Note the `InfoArray` farther down the page.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Note that `__new__` is a static method and it takes the subclass as the first argument. The rest of `__new__`'s signatures do not have object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR: it's the `buffer` argument to `np.ndarray.__new__(...)`.  The numpy docs on subclassing discuss creating a new object, a view, and a new-from-template.  They show you how to create a new object of your subclass from scratch `MySubClass(...)` and a view object of your subclass `arr.view(MySubClass)`, but they don't show you how to create a new-from-template of your subclass, other than mentioning that it happens in slicing.

You can see this by:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = 2 * np.ones(3)
np.ndarray.__new__(np.ndarray, shape=(1,), dtype=float, buffer=arr)
```

gives `array([2.])`.  Obviously, the object template is passed as a buffer, so things like striding, order, shape, dtype affect how the data in `arr` is interpreted.

As @tim-roberts pointed out, the `InfoArray` example is helpful, and in fact contains the complete call signature.  I couldn't find it myself, possibly as numpy._core.__init__.pyi is deliberately left empty.  Nevertheless, the type checker did find the full signature:

```py
(cls: type[_ArraySelf@__new__], shape: _ShapeLike,
dtype: DTypeLike = ..., buffer: _SupportsBuffer | None = ...,
offset: SupportsIndex = ..., strides: _ShapeLike | None = ...,
order: _OrderKACF = ...) -> _ArraySelf@__new__
```

My use case, since Tim asked: My subclass carries around properties that refer to axes definitions (e.g. `arr.ax_time`) in order to make some math clearer (e.g. `differentiate(arr, axis=arr.ax_time)`).  That meant that `ndarray.view(MyClass)` doesn't make a whole lot of sense, so I wanted to modify the example test (test_ufunc_override_with_super) that used standard views to use new-from-template instead.  I know I can test this via slicing (I modify `__getitem__`), but I wasn't sure if that was the only way new-from-template is used.